# How to display the interfaces of a particular dbus bus name (/org/bluez) in python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, dbus, bluez

I would like to find out what are the available objects and interfaces in the bluez dbus bus. I wrote a simple python script to list all the bus names in the dbus session.

```
import dbus
for service in dbus.SystemBus().list_names():
    print(service)
```

However, I am only interested in the interfaces inside bluez /org/bluez. How can a python script be written to list down the interfaces inside /org/bluez?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
system_bus = dbus.SystemBus()
objectManager = system_bus.get_object('org.bluez', '/')
om_iface = dbus.Interface(objectManager, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager')

ifacelist = om_iface.GetManagedObjects()
```

Where `ifacelist` is a Dict of {ObjectPath, Dictof{String, Variant}}}

Comment: I got the following error. What are some possibilities of what went wrong? Thanks. 
`dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist`

Comment: Which version of bluez do you have?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is using Bluez 4.XX. I think it is 4.101
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/bluez

Comment: Oops my solution works with bluez 5. See http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/